# Simulation results: difference, absolute error, relative error

Tags: statistics

I am wrinting a paper and I want to compare results of two different simulations (different model complexity).

In one case
 1. A detailed model
 2. A simplified model

and in another case two different model approaches (but same level of detail)

Lets assume two temperature trajectories. Would you call the difference "(abs, rel) error" or just "difference" or is there another term for that? Since I have no measured (or real) data.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: "Would you call the differences "abs, rel) error" or just "difference"?

Comment: Each one of these terms has a specific meaning, which one are you measuring?

Comment: If I have two simulation results - and I want to plot the difference of these - should I neam it "error" (rel or abs), or "difference"?

Comment: Unless you want to be misleading, if you are plotting the difference between two things, then you should call it what it is, a difference.

Comment: Ok, thank you - and is it  common to plot a "relative difference"? Lets say I introduce the result from sim1 as "reference"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call it what it is, it really depends on what you want to show.

Say you want to compare scalars $x$ and $y$ and that you take $x$ as your reference:

- The difference is $y-x$
- The absolute error is $|x-y|$
- The relative error is $(y-x)/x$

If $x$ and $y$ are vectors, then you have several other choices:

- Norm of the difference $\|x-y\|$
- Cosine similarity $\cos(x,y) = \frac{x\cdot y}{\|x\|\|y\|}$
- Correlation $\cos( x-\bar{x}, y-\bar{y} )$

If they are time-series, or matrices, or images, there are yet other ways of comparing them. Without a more specific question, this is the best answer I can give.